# Issue in Android-Twitter integration

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, android-twitter

I have integrated `Twitter` in android application using twitter4j library and it works fine with posting on `Twitter`.

I handle it well when user signs in and then flow comes back to application. I continue with status update in this case.

But the problem occurs when user clicks `cancel` button instead of `sign in`. How do I know that user clicked `cancel` button?

Comment: Dare to answer if you have any, instead of down voting. Also post the reason for your down vote.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by peeking into Intent passed in call back.
When user signs in, Intent contains a parameter `oauth_verifier`, whereas when user denies to continue by clicking on `cancel` button, Intent contains a parameter `denied`.

```
// Handle Twitter call back
private void handleTwitterCallBack() {

    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();

    // If got redirected from Twitter page to application
    if (uri != null
            && uri.toString().startsWith(RS_Twitter.TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {

        if (uri.getQueryParameter(RS_Twitter.TWITTER_USER_DENIED) != null) {

            // User denied to sign in

        } else if (uri
                .getQueryParameter(RS_Twitter.TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER_URL) != null) {

            // Intent contains Twitter verifier. User authorized the application.
        }
    }
}
```